# Stop the execution of the method from another method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

please tell me how to stop the execution of the `Script()` from `CheckStr()`.

**example**

```
public void Script()
{
// ...
    string str = "error";
    CheckStr(str);
// ...
}
public void CheckStr(string str)
{
    if (str == "error")
    {
         // stop Script();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Throw an exception in checkstr?

Comment: `Application.Exit()` is one way to "stop" its execution.. it would be much nicer to let the user know what is going on though... What have you tried/researched?

Comment: @Sayse I know that i can stop method using `return`. But it turns out too much code. I think it's just impossible. I guess my question is impossible to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let `CheckStr()` return a value:

```
public void Script()
{
    string str = "error";
    if (!CheckStr(str))
    {
        return;
    }

    // ...continue
}

public bool CheckStr(string str)
{
    if (str == "error")
    {
        return false;
    }

    // ...additional checks

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could throw an exception from `CheckStr`, but I'm not sure if that would solve your particular problem:

```
public void CheckStr(string str)
{
    if (str == "error")
    {
         throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

You could then catch it, either in `Script`, or elsewhere:

```
public void Script()
{
// ...
    string str = "error";
    try {
       CheckStr(str);
    }
    catch
    {
        // handle excpetion here.
    }
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to have `CheckStr` return a result, e.g. `true/false`

```
public bool CheckStr(string str)
{
    if (str == "error")
    {
        return false;
    }
    ...
    return true;
}

public void Script()
{
    // ...
    string str = "error";
    if (CheckStr(str) == false)
    {
        return;
    }
    // ...
}
```